# C# LINQ query - No implicit conversion error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have defined the following entity classes for my LINQ query:

```
public class Application
{
    public Application() { }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? DateTimeModified { get; set; }
    public Employee CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Employee ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public Employee() { }

    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I have created the following query to create an `Application` object and trying to create an `Employee` entity for the `CreatedBy` and 'ModifiedBy' properties.  Sometimes, the `ModifiedBy` column can contain null and I want to set the `ModifiedBy` property to null.

```
var query = from a in context.Applications
            join u1 in context.Employees on a.CreatedBy equals u1.Employee_ID.Trim()
            join u2 in context.Employees on a.ModifiedBy equals u2.Employee_ID.Trim()  
            where a.ApplicationId == applicationId
            select new Entity.Application
            {
                Id = a.ApplicationId,
                Name = a.ApplicationName,
                Description = a.ApplicationDesc,
                DateTimeCreated = a.DateTimeCreated,
                CreatedBy = new Entity.Employee{ EmployeeID = a.CreatedBy, FirstName = u1.First_Name, LastName = u1.Last_Name },
                DateTimeModified = a.DateTimeModified ?? null,
                ModifiedBy = (a.ModifiedBy != null) ? new Entity.Employee { EmployeeID = a.ModifiedBy, FirstName = u2.First_Name, LastName = u2.Last_Name } : (Entity.Employee) null,
             };
```

When I debug the query above, I get the following error:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
>   no implicit conversion between 'Employee' and 'Application'

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: what is the field/property `ApplicationId` - should that be just `Id`?

Comment: So the query above works if you remove this line? `ModifiedBy = (a.ModifiedBy != null) ? new Entity.Employee { EmployeeID = a.ModifiedBy, FirstName = u2.First_Name, LastName = u2.Last_Name } : (Entity.Employee) null,`

Comment: @nate - yes, I get past that error when I removed the line referenced in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional research, here is the revised code snippet that ended up working for me:

```
var result = (from a in context.Applications
               join u1 in context.Employee on a.CreatedBy equals u1.Employee_ID.Trim()
               join u2 in context.Employee on a.ModifiedBy equals u2.Employee_ID.Trim() into us
               from u2 in us.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where a.ApplicationId == applicationId
               select new Entity.Application()
               {
                   Id = a.ApplicationId,
                   Name = a.ApplicationName,
                   Description = a.ApplicationDesc,
                   DateTimeCreated = a.DateTimeCreated,
                   CreatedBy = new Entity.Employee
                   {
                       EmployeeID = a.CreatedBy,
                       FirstName = u1.First_Name,
                       LastName = u1.Last_Name
                   },
                   DateTimeModified = a.DateTimeModified ?? null,
                   ModifiedBy = new Entity.Employee
                   {
                       EmployeeID = a.ModifiedBy ?? string.Empty,
                       FirstName = u2.First_Name ?? string.Empty,
                       LastName = u2.Last_Name ?? string.Empty
                   }
               }).Single();
```

Answer (score 3):

It may not directly address an error you're getting, but you don't need that query at all, because you have navigation properties set. Use `Include` instead and it should work just fine - EF will join necessary joins for you:

```
var query context.Applications
                 .Include("ModifiedBy")
                 .Include("CreatedBy")
                 .Where(a => a.ApplicationId == applicationId);
```

Comment: When I try to look at the results view of this query, I get the following message in debug mode: Children could not be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

A couple things I am noticing

```
 join u1 in context.Employees on a.CreatedBy equals u1.Employee_ID.Trim()
 join u2 in context.Employees on a.ModifiedBy equals u2.Employee_ID.Trim()
```

You can't join like this, as `CreateBy` and `ModifiedBy` are of type `Employee`, not `string`

Also, have a look at this:

```
 (Entity.Employee) null
```

You can't cast null to `Employee`. You might want to use the type's default value in future:

```
 default(Entity.Employee)
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in the comments, it is legal to cast null to `Entity.Employee`, but since you end up with null anyways there is not much point to the exercise. `default(Entity.Employee)` also results in null, since that's the default value for reference types, but `default` could provide a different value for various other types, which can sometimes be useful.

Comment: I agree with `join`, but you definitely can cast `null` to `Entity.Employee`.

Comment: Indeed! I must have brought some assumptions forward from my pre-C# days!

Comment: The `CreatedBy` and `ModifiedBy` columns in the context Applications table are defined as string.  I am doing the join to get the employee information from the context `Employee` view

Comment: @MichaelKniskern Why would those fields of type `Employee` in your `Application` model?